# display tags on catalogue pages woo commerce - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I'm looking like a crazy person if there is a way to display the tags of a product on the catalogue page with woocommerce ( wordpress plugin). I can not find anything about ti and I've been trying to tweak the code, but without success . . .

if anybody has some high lite, it will be wonderful,

thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example will show product tags on shop archive pages. The code is taken from the single product meta template ( `single-product/meta.php` ), so HTML will be the same as in single product pages. The function is hooked to `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action ( the tags will be between the main content and the add_to_cart content ), if you want to place them elsewhere open the `content-product.php` and `wc-template-hooks.php` plugin files, to see all the available actions and priorities of functions attached, and attach `woocommerce_product_loop_tags` function to a different action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;

    $tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );

    echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
}
```

Comment: this is great, thank you !

By any chance, do you know how to change the style of only the tag in the archive page ? IF I change the span class_tagged_as by a style, it does work, but only ont he first tag, I have several tag . .. 

Another problem I have is that now, the button Add to Cart is totally moved outside of the "product box", if you ahve any solution  .. . thank you so much !!

Comment: I fixed all of it,

last thing: It's working perfectly thank you, just one thing, I've a big gap everytime between each tag after the ","< That's because I'used some margin-left to center the all thing, but it apply to each tag, anyway to apply the style to center the "all tag" ??

Thank you =)