# Show product tags description in woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I am building a woocommerce website, and I am wrestling to get the tag description on the shop page. I found a lot of info about the tags themselves, and this code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753220/display-tags-on-catalogue-pages-woo-commerce-wordpress) shows the tags perfectly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
global $post, $product;

$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );

echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
}
```

But, It shows the Tag Title only, and I want to see the description of the tags

To be more specific: The ultimate goal is to show a picture/icon depending on the tag. That is why I added an picture in the tag description.
But if someone knows a better/easier solution to show a picture depending on the tag, I'll be glad to know :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is a bit oldish and outdated since WooCommerce 3…
The `WC_Product` method `get_tags()` has been replaced by [**`wc_get_product_tag_list()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product_tag_list.html#997-1008) function.

As [`wc_get_product_tag_list()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product_tag_list.html#997-1008) function use the WordPress [`get_the_term_list()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1226) function for 'product_tag' custom taxonomy *(Woocommerce product tags)*, we will use some similar code.

In the function below, you will be able to get the product tag description, but to output a thumbnail (or icon) for each product tag, the best way should be:

> **Product tag thumbnail / icon:**
>
> Add in your active child theme *(or active theme)* a folder that contain all your product tags icons. 
> This folder name will be `icon_tags` (for example). 
> Each icon file name will be the product tag slug .

Once your icons are generated and uploaded in that `icon_tags` sub folder *(with the correct file names)* in your active theme folder, set in the code below the correct image path:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_product_tags', 5 );
function woocommerce_product_loop_product_tags() {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'product_tag'; // Product tag custom taxonomy
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) || count( $terms ) == 0 )
        return;

    ## -- BELOW define your product tag images path -- ##

    // $path = get_template_directory_uri(); // For a Normal theme
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); // For a child theme
    $img_path = $path . '/icon_tags/';

    $links = array();

    // Loop through each product tag
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_id = $term->term_id; // term ID
        $term_slug = $term->slug; // term slug
        $term_name = $term->name; // term name
        $term_description = $term->description; // (if needed)
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

        // Image for product tag
        $image_src = $img_path . $term->slug . '.jpg';
        $image = '<img src="' . esc_url( $image_src ) . '" alt="" >';

        $product_tags[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $image . '<span class="caption">' . $term_name . '</span></a>';
    }

    $sep = ', ';
    $before = '<p class="tagged_as"><strong>' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $terms ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' </strong>';
    $after = '</p>';

    echo $before . join( $sep, $product_tags ) . $after;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

This code is tested and works.

> You should certainly have to make some changes in the html output and in the related CSS styling rules…

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I added the code in the functions.php

Comment: something went wrong with editing, but thanks, works like a charm!